# EventStore example applications with source?

Tags: neventstore

can anyone point me to any [EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore) sample application with source code?

I'm learning event storing and want to view a reference implementation.

Comment: Not sure what your development stack is, but I found the Samples folder in the NCQRS project on GitHub to be a good start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a lack of full-featured sample projects for a lot of this stuff.  So far the best option for EventStore/CommonDomain that I've found is [Haf's Documently](https://github.com/haf/Documently) project on GitHub.  You can find both source code and wiki pages there.  It seems to gloss over some of the complications of real-world apps but it was enough to get me started with my own prototyping.